# tkinter: how to inherit widgets from another .py file

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 3 rather large tkinter files, each working perfectly, but would like to have them placed on one screen: how to use pages I have learned recently from this forum (TY).
Now, I would like to have most of the coding for the separate pages done in separate .py files. However, especially in case of widgets, I can not figure out how to use the frame names in the separate .py file. I do realize, as I tried it, that the function for the label creation is

way shortened example:

**Main.py**

```
from functions import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Kombucha Program")
root.geometry("1400x800")
root.minsize(width=900, height=600)
    #root.maxsize(width=1400, height = 900)
root.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.configure( bg = '#000080' )

theFrame = tk.Frame(root, width=1200, height = 630, bg = 'yellow')       #0059b3')
theFrame.grid(column=0,row=1, sticky = N, in_ = root)

getlabels()

mainloop()
```

**functions.py**

```
def getLabels():
    exitButton = tk.Button(theFrame, text="Quit the Program",  width = 12, command=root.destroy)
    exitButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as your code in question is concerned, you will have to pass the frame as an argument to the function.

```
def getLabels(theFrame):
    root = theFrame.master # Get the parent window from the frame itself
    exitButton = tk.Button(theFrame, text="Quit the Program",  width = 12, command=root.destroy)
    exitButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

...and while calling it, pass the required frame:

```
getlabels(theFrame)
```

Also notice that I extracted `root` from the frame as `root` it is not within the scope of `functions.py`. But honestly you can make the structure of your project more better if you use classes and make each frame as a class.

Comment: Simply use `theFrame.master` to refer its parent.

Comment: @acw1668 Oh thanks :) I completely forgot such a variable existed

Comment: Cool Cloud,  TY again.
I actually am researching classes since you have given me the last answer of 'multiple pages' yesterday.  And, I am going to use your example and build on it. But first I need to understand classes and will continue researching them until I do understand.
TY AGAIN!!!

Comment: @rfeyer No problem :) would appreciate an upvote

Comment: Hey Cool Cloud,  I did do the green checkmark - if that is not an upvote, I will research that too - you certainly deserve all the praise I can give

Comment: @rfeyer No probs, take a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It means simply clicking on the triangle facing upwards. I hope you go ahead and do that towards all the people that answers you and you found helpful